# SQL query assigment

Tags: mysql, sql

1) Query that returns all agents who had sales greater or equal than 20 in month March, also sum of sales in month March greater or equal than 20 and number of sales in month March greater or equal than 20. Results sort in descending order.
Colons: name, amount, count

2) Query that returns all agents who didn't have even one sale greater than 20 in month March.
Colon: name

Database:

DBSale

ID ____ IDAgent _____ Date ____ Amount

1 _______ 1 ______  01-03-16 _____  15

2 _______   2 ______        01-03-16 _____      25

3 _______   1 ______        01-03-16 _____      17

4 _______   3 ______        04-03-16 _____      55

5 _______   4 ______        04-03-16 _____      12

6 _______   5 ______        05-03-16 _____      13

7 _______   5 ______        06-03-16 _____      11

8 _______   4 ______        11-03-16 _____      20

9 _______   4 ______        12-03-16 _____      21

10 ______   3 ______        15-03-16 _____      45

11 ______       2 ______        17-03-16 _____      45

12 ______       1 ______        19-03-16 _____      11

13 ______       1 ______        25-03-16 _____      19

14 ______       1 ______        01-04-13 _____      25

15 ______       1 ______        04-04-16 _____      65

16 ______       3 ______        15-04-16 _____      10

17 ______       5 ______        16-04-16 _____      41

DBUser

ID ___  Name

1 ___       Mark Roseberg

2 ___       Don Smith

3 ___       Anna Twix

4 ___       Angela Reeves

5 ___       Juan Dovitoso

These are my incorrect tries:

1)

```
SELECT u.name SUM(s.amount) AS amount, COUNT(s.amount) AS count
FROM dbuser AS u JOIN dbsale AS s
ON u.id = s.idagent
ORDER BY s.amount ASC
HAVING s.amount >= 20 AND MONTH(s.date)='3';
```

2)

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.name
FROM dbuser AS u INNER JOIN dbsale AS s
ON u.id = s.idagent
WHERE s.amount < 20 AND MONTH(s.date)='3' ;
```

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and whats your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query 1 will be-

```
SELECT 
A.`name`, 
SUM(B.amount) AS amount, 
COUNT(B.amount) AS count 
FROM DBUser A
INNER JOIN DBSale B ON A.ID = B.IDAgent
WHERE MONTH(CAST(B.date AS DATE))=3
AND B.amount >= 20
GROUP BY A.`name`
```

And query 2 will be-

```
SELECT A.`name`
FROM DBUser A
INNER JOIN DBSale B 
ON A.ID = B.IDAgent
WHERE MONTH(CAST(B.date AS DATE))=3
GROUP BY A.`name`,A.ID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN B.Amount > 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Add order by as per your requirement.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Query two is most likely invalid and should give a error.. Unless functional dependency can be used -> [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)